# get value of 2 composant datepicker in onChange (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, material-ui

I'm using the DatePicker component of materialui and I need to get the value of two DatePicker components in one function to make a range.

I created a handleChange function that already allows to retrieve the value of a DatePicker component but for 2 component I can not do it.

I would like to know the steps I need to take.

this is my code :

```js
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr'
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
import areIntlLocalesSupported from 'intl-locales-supported';


let DateTimeFormat;

if (areIntlLocalesSupported(['fr'])) {
  DateTimeFormat = global.Intl.DateTimeFormat;
} else {
    const IntlPolyfill = require('intl');
    DateTimeFormat = IntlPolyfill.DateTimeFormat;
    require('intl/locale-data/jsonp/fr');
    require('intl/locale-data/jsonp/fa-IR');
}


class SearchByDate extends React.Component {

  handleSearchByDate = (evt, date) => {
    console.log(date)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
            ref="dateChoiceOne"
            name="dateChoiceOne"
            hintText="Date début"
            DateTimeFormat={DateTimeFormat}
            okLabel="OK"
            cancelLabel="Annuler"
            locale="fr"
            onChange={this.handleSearchByDate}/>

        <DatePicker
            ref="dateChoiceTwo"
            name="dateChoiceTwo"
            hintText="Date fin"
            DateTimeFormat={DateTimeFormat}
            okLabel="OK"
            cancelLabel="Annuler"
            locale="fr"
            onChange={this.handleSearchByDate} />
      </div> 
    )
  }
}

export default SearchByDate;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try logging `evt.target.name` inside `handleSearchByDate`

Comment: @anand I tried but it does not work. And when I read the Material UI doc for the DatePicker component, I saw that the "event" parameter of the function that the onChange property is calling returns a null. (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker) => Signature:
function(null: undefined, date: object) => void
null: Since there is no particular event associated with the change, the first argument will always be null.
date: The new date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the date selection from the 1st DatePicker and the 2nd DatePicker happens at different times, you can't get the 2 dates as arguments into the function.

Instead, you should create 2 differents functions, one for each DatePicker. Theses functions will save the dates as `startDate` and `endDate`, and you can check for state updates in `componentDidUpdate` ; once you have both dates set, you can do whatever you wanted to.

```
class SearchByDate extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    if (this.state.startDate && this.state.endDate) {
      // Both dates are set, do something with it
    }
  }

  handleChangeStartDate = (evt, date) => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date,
    });
  }

  handleChangeEndDate = (evt, date) => {
    this.setState({
      endDate: date,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          ref="dateChoiceOne"
          name="dateChoiceOne"
          hintText="Date début"
          DateTimeFormat={DateTimeFormat}
          okLabel="OK"
          cancelLabel="Annuler"
          locale="fr"
          onChange={this.handleChangeStartDate}
        />

        <DatePicker
          ref="dateChoiceTwo"
          name="dateChoiceTwo"
          hintText="Date fin"
          DateTimeFormat={DateTimeFormat}
          okLabel="OK"
          cancelLabel="Annuler"
          locale="fr"
          onChange={this.handleChangeEndDate}
        />
      </div> 
    )
  }
}
```